# Use complex numbers to produce the equilateral triangle as illustrated below with its center at the origin and one point at (3, 4).

Tags: complex-numbers, fixed-point-theorems, math-software

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmBMz.png)
[image]

thanks very much!

Comment: anyone know this ????

Comment: Yes !!!! ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The unknown coordinates of the second and third point are those of the first point rotated around the origin by 120 resp. 240 degrees. In the complex numbers, a rotation around the origin by $\theta$ is a multiplication by $\exp(i\theta)$.

Comment: Very nice hint. I{ll add a further little hint: the points obtained by rotation as Wouter explains **must be** at the same distance from the origin as $\;(3,4)\;$ (why?). +1

Comment: I’ve forgotten the rotation formula...can u tell me??thanks

Comment: As I said, just multiply by $\exp(i\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the rotation angle in radians.